# SQL Server foreign key contsraint preventing insert, where no conflict exits

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables, and I have just done an insert of about 1,000,000 rows. I turned off foreign key constraints , but I have an error when I try and reinstate them with

```
ALTER TABLE ForexRebatesNow.dbo.Transactions WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

I get the following error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint  "FK_Transactions_RebateAccounts". The conflict occurred in database "ForexRebatesNow", table "dbo.RebateAccounts", column 'Id'.

So I go to look for `RebateAccountId` that does not have a corresponding `Id` in the `RebateAccounts` table

```
SELECT Id 
FROM ForexRebatesNow.dbo.RebateAccounts 
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT RebateAccountId 
                 FROM ForexRebatesNow.dbo.Transactions)
```

But this returns zero rows, so in my mind that conflict does  not exist.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT

The relationship between `RebateAccounts` and `Transactions` is One to Many. `RebateAccountId` is a Nullable int on Transactions table as not all`Transactions` will have an associated `RebateAccount`, but any `RebateAccount` can have many `Transactions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not provided the relations between the two tables, I assume that there is a `One-to-Many` relation between `RebateAccounts` and `Transactions` Table. If I'm right then I guess you are checking the conflict in an opposite way. Your foreign key in in the `dbo.Transactions` table but you are checking it with the `dbo.RebateAccounts` table.

Try the following query to find the conflict.

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE RebateAccountId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM RebateAccounts)
```

If any row shows up then that row has an account id that does not belong to any account. That's where your conflict is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ive tried running the query the other way around as you suggest, but it still shows up with zero results. Ive edited my question to provide clarity on the relationship between the 2 entities

Comment: My mistake, I ran that query on the dev server where the data is different. running it on the production server highlighted the conflicting Ids.